# Is it better using Parse than setting my own authentication?

Tags: ios, authentication, networking, parse-platform

I am using Parse service for my authentication in my iOS application.

I am beginner and I do not have enough information for setting my own authentication server. So far I have made some progress with Parse in my application. So my question is the following.

Should I train myself for learning setting my own server for authentication and implement that in my application or should I just keep going to use Parse? Please note that Parse is letting 1.000.000 api request for month in free edition (I think this is a sufficient number for a application with average user account but I would be happy to see your oppinions).

While it is personal question i would please to see different aspects. So be free to share your ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very personal answer based on my experience and preferences.

Parse is a very good service and idea that allows you to think only to the application and leave out complicated stuff like networking. At the same time it forces you to stay tied with it. So, for example, what could it happen if tomorrow services are limited (not more 1.000.000 API requests) or stopped (I hope not)?

Yes, networking is complicated but also challenging. So, IMHO, if you want to be a good developer, go and create your own service.

To start you can set up a REST architecture where JSON is used for messaging. This is quite simple to achieve in many programming languages (PHP, JAVA, Rails, etc.). Out of there, you can find very good external libraries (like **AFNetworking**) that can be used to configure the communication in your application.

You can find a complete example where authentication has been set up at [Authentication with AFNetworking](http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/41-authentication-with-afnetworking).

P.S. You can see the video only if you are a subscriber but code is free of charge on Github. Follow the links.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for your informative answer. i will use your guide for my decisions.